# How to test javascript geolocation using VPN?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

so I want to test if users get a different landing page when coming in from overseas.

like Indian site visitors gets an Indian focused website/services. While domestic visitors get local website/services meant for them.

So I tried using VPN and the browser still knows my real location. Is there a way to fool it so I can test?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the remote address for the header of the requests? Is your local address or VPN's?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you can try is to set a Fake Geolocation.

Use the VPN to connect to the country of your choice and use the following chrome extension to set the Geo-location. Turn it on and move the latitude and longitude that you set the VPN to and give it a shot.

[image]